# How to change a value used in a for loop inside the loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Sorry for bad title, but I can't find better wording for it. For example, if I have something like this

```
int count=0;
For(int x=0;x<=10;x++)
{
     if(x==1)
     {
         .........//do something;
     }
     else if(x==2)
     {
         count++;
         .........//do something;
         If (count==1)
         {
          //set x back to zero;
         }
     }
     //...........
}
```

How do I set x back to zero in this loop?

Comment: Um... `x = 0;`?

Comment: You'll also need to assign an initial value to `count` outside the loop.

Comment: Nothing stops you from just setting it to 0 just like you would with any other variable.  You didn't try that before asking?  Be braver when experimenting with your code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mabye:

```
int count = 0;
for(int x=0;x<=10;x++)
{
     if(x==1)
     {
         .........//do something;
     }
     else if(x==2)
     {
         count++;
         .........//do something;
         if (count==1)
         {
              x=0;
         }
     }
     //...........
}
```

Remember that `a==b` is equation used in if statement, which indicates if a is equal to b, and `a=b` sets a value to value of b;

Hope I helped :)